# Why does it actually matter whether $m \leq n$ or $m>n$ in computing the SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

[image]

I am learning how to compute SVD now and I ran across a question. Why does it actually matter whether $m \leq n$ or $m>n$ in computing the SVD?

As I read through the motivation of SVD I found out that if $A = U\Sigma V^T$ the eigenvectors of $AA^T$ corresponds to the orthogonal matrix $U$, while the eigenvectors of $A^TA$ corresponds to the orthogonal matrix $V$. And since $Av_i = \sigma_i u_i$ and $A^Tu_i = \sigma_iv_i$ I do not see any reason we must enforce the 2 cases. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Given the connection between the SVD of $A$ and of $A^T$, I tend to agree with you.  The way it's set out in this book minimizes the size of matrix to be eigen-analyzed, and avoids the problem of dividing by zero eigenvalues if you do it the other way: both of these might be of some practical utility.  But unless $p$ is tiny, I don't think anyone actually uses this method to compute the SVD.